# Why not use pickle instead of struct?

Tags: python, struct, pickle

I am unable to understand the use of `pickle` module vs. the `struct` module. Both convert a Python object into a byte stream. It seems easier to use `pickle` than to do the packing and unpacking of the `struct` module. So when is `pickle` used and when is `struct` used?

Comment: Because pickle is more bloated, and because sometimes the output stream has to follow a specific protocol.

Comment: https://konstantin.blog/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/ <-- Really want this kind of performance in your data app? The go with Pickle  - it is mega slow, and kind of unnecessary

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Are you only talking  about string streams and tuples or other serializable structures?

Comment: @jwpfox: This question could generate some interesting benchmarks, among other things. I don't think it will bring only opinion-based answers. I think we should give this question a chance.

Comment: @Lissy: the two are not equivalent. JSON can only serialize vanilla objects by default, nor can it for instance detect that two variables refer to the same object. In case there is a cyclic dependency,  it will error (whereas pickle keeps track of the objects it has pickled, and creates a backreference).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what `struct` does.

## Struct

Struct is *not* meant to store *Python* objects into a byte stream. What it does is producing a byte stream by *transforming* Python *objects* into *structures* that represent the *data* the objects contained. For instance used a signed 32-bit representation for an integer. But a `struct` for instance is *not* designed to store a dictionary, since there are a lot of ways to serialize a dictionary.

It is used to construct a (binary) file that meets the criteria of a protocol. For instance if you have a 3d model, then you perhaps want to write an exporter to the [*`.3ds` file format*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds). This format follows a certain protocol (for instance it will start with `0x4d4d`). You can not use pickle to dump to such format, since Pickle is actually a specific protocol.

The same with reading binary files into Python objects. You can not run Pickle over a `.3ds` file, since Pickle does *not* know the protocol. It does not know what `0x4d4d` in the beginning of the file means. It can be a 16-bit integer (`19789`), it can be a 2-character ASCII string (`'MM')`, etc. Usually most binary files are designed for one purpose. And you need to understand the *protocol* in order to read/write such files.

## Pickle

Pickle on the other hand is a tool designed to store *Python objects* in a binary stream, such that we can load these objects back once we need these. It defines a protocol. For instance pickle always starts the stream with byte `128`, followed by the protocol version (`1`, `2`, or `3`). The next byte specifies an identifier of the type of object we are going to pickle (for instance `75` for an integer, `88` for a string, etc.

Pickle also has to serialize all references of the object, and keep track of the objects it has already serialized, since there can be cyclic structures into it. For instance if we have two dictionaries:

```
d = {}
e = {'a': d}
d['a'] = e
```

then we can not simply serialize `d`, and serialize `e` as part of `e`. We have to keep track that we serialized `d` already, since serializing `e` would otherwise resulting serializing `d`, etc. until we run out of memory.

Pickle is thus a specific protocol to store *Python* objects. But we can not use it to serialize to a specific format, such that other (non-Python) programs can read it.

Answer (score 6):

Because they do quite different things.

You can serialize objects in different ways:

- text serialization formats: here the serialized object is human readable. Common formats are json and xml, or csv for lists of simple *rows*. But except for very simply objects (arrays, dictionaries and simple data), you need to define a marshalling protocol to save the relevant part of an object and then rebuild the object from its serialized version
- binary serialization formats:

  - pickle is intended to automatically serialize an object, and allow it to be automatically deserialized back provided the class is available at deserialization time. Its major drawback is that it is only useable from Python
  - struct is the opposite: you must specifically decide what you save and in what format. And at deserialization time, you also have to know what format was used. But it can be used to exchange binary streams with any other language, provided the format is clearly defined

TL/DR the question is not about performance (even if some conversions could be slightly more resource consuming than others) but more on what it the objective of serialization: pickle for local *backups*, struct for external exchanges

Answer (score 0):

`Pickle` is mostly used to save a `checkpoint` of the current state of a data, so that it can be used by some other `Python Process`. It is convenient, as you don't have to care a about what you have to serialize, as `pickle` handles class instances, shared elements, and recursive data structures, among other things.

`Struct` in contrary always comes with a `protocol` which is a `description` that defines how to read the data, without that, you can't unpack the data.

Btw. those are not the only libraries that dump/serialize data, there is a good summary of some of the methods: http://effbot.org/librarybook/data-representation-index.htm